# res.rendr is not loading a complete file

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

in my code res.render is not loading a complete file instead it only shows a first page of the  file

```
PersonalInfo.findOne({ name:'amna'}, function(err,post){
       if(err || !posts)
       {
           console.log("find is not done");
       }

      else{
               console.log(post);
              res.render("/profilearea.ejs");

          })
```

Comment: .findOne() is not a list of posts. it's just one post. Also, you can just do res.render('/profilearea');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to the callback of `findOne` isn't an array, it's just a single model instance (or `null`).  Did you mean to to use `find` instead?

Comment: I only want to find one data with the name :amna .the name is present in the database but it always print "find is not done " @JohnyHK

Comment: can you please guide me in writing find query @JohnyHK